# dynamic method binding in java - why this method?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
public class A {

    public void m1(A a) {
        System.out.println("m1(A) in A");
    }

    public void m4() {
        System.out.println("m4() in A");
    }
}

public class B extends A{

    public void m1(B b) {
        System.out.println("m1(B) in B");
    }

    public void m4() {
        System.out.println("m4() in B");
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b = new B();
        A a = b;
        a.m1(b); // returns m1(A) in A
        a.m4();  // returns m4() in B
    }

}
```

Can someone please explain why `a.m1(b)` uses the method of A and `a.m4()` uses the method of B?

I particularly don't understand how this one variable (`a`) invokes methods of two different classes. I thought that at runtime, `a` is either seen as an A or a B, which then should result in either both methods from A or both methods from B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the basics of object declaration.

Let's consider a class `Animal`.

```
Animal anim=new Animal();
```

`Anim anim` tells JVM to create a new reference variable of type Animal and the `new Animal()` asks the JVM to create a new `Animal` object. Both these statements combined by `=` tells JVM to create a reference variable of type `Animal` and assign a animal object to it.

What does `anim` ?

- `anim` is similar to a remote control which controls the behaviour of an object of type `Animal`. We use it to refer to the object.

I hope it's clear till now.

Now let us move on to Inheritance and Polymorphism. Consider a new class `Dog` which extends `Animal`. `Dog` becomes a sub-class of `Animal` .

In case of inheritance, you could consider the `IS A` rule. In this case, since `Dog` has extended `Animal` , `Dog` IS A `Animal`. I hope you got me. This is where polymorphism comes into picture. Polymorphism means you can actually use a super class reference variable to refer to a sub class object.

```
Animal anim1=new Dog();
```

We have created a remote control `anim1` which controls a `Dog` object. This `anim1` reference (remote control) can only control `Animal` specific methods of class `Dog`. This remote control can also control the over-ridden methods but can not control any new method in `Dog` which is not inherited or over-ridden.

Now, Let us move on to your classes `A` and `B`. `B` IS-A  `A`  since it has extended `A`.

This means `A a= new B();` is true by polymorphism. This is similar to what yoh have done using the below code:

```
B b=new B();
A a=b;
```

Now why does `a.m1(b);` go to method in `A` 
and `a.m4();` go to `B`?

Let us look at something else before going to that:

You have a method in class `A` as:
`public void m1(A a)`

You have a method in class `B` as:
`public void m1(B b)`

Overriding means you are actually redefining a inherited method in the sub class. So in your case, `m1(B b)` in class `B` is not over-riding since the paraneter it has is different. The parameter it has is of type `B` while the original `m1(A a)` in `A` looks for argument of type `A`. In short, your class `B` has 2 methods named as `m1`.
One which is inherited from `A` and a new method or over-loaded method with a parameter type `B`.

Like I have already mentioned, our remote control `a` can only see the method which is specific to class `A`. It can't see the over-loaded method. That's the reason, it's actually going to the inherited method `m1(A a)`.

Now, `a.m4();` goes to `m4()` in `B`. why?

- Because `m4()` in `B` is an over-ridden method and `a` can see it.

Had you called `b.m1(b)`, method in `B` would have been used.

Summing up:
You can use a super class reference variable/remote to refer/point to a sub-class object but this remote can only see inherited methods including over-ridden but not over loaded.
But a reference of sub class type will be able to see all the methods.

To help you identify over-ridden and overloaded methods:

Over-ridden method are like:

- Arguments must be same and parameters must be same or compatible.
- Method can not be less accessible. That is `public` cannot be made `private`.

Overloaded methods like:

- Returns types can be different.
- There should be some change in argument type or number of arguments should be different.
- Access levels can be changed

Using the above rules, you can easily idebtify that `m1(B b)` in `B` was actually a overloaded method since the parameter type varies from `m1(A a)`.

Finally, `B` possessed 3 methods:

- `m1(A a)` inherted
- `m1(B b)` overloaded
- `m4()` over-ridden

Please comment if you have any doubts or in case of an error.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much for your effort! My mistake was to assume that m1(B b) is an override, because every B is also an A. But now it actually makes sense that it isn't. Great answer!

Comment: I am glad that it helped you. Happy Learning.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `B.m1(B)` doesn't override `A.m1(A)`. It's an overload instead because its parameter is a different type.

In order to override it, you would need to change the parameter type to `A`.

Note that it's always a good idea to annotate methods that you *think* you are overriding with `@Override`: then the compiler will tell you if you aren't really overriding the method.

Note also that if you called `b.m1(b);` it *would* call the method on `B`, since that overload is more specific that `A.m1(A)`. However, with the current code the only method which can be matched at compile time is `A.m1(A)`, since all is known is that `a` is either an instance of `A` or one of its subtypes: the only methods which are known to be available are the methods on `A`.

The invoked method is chosen at compile time, not runtime.

Comment: But then why does a.m4() return the message of the B-method?

Comment: Because that *is* overriding `A.m4()`. It has the same parameters (both have zero) and the same return type (`void`) (strictly, the return types need not exactly match: the overriding method's return type must be covariant with that of the overridden method).

Comment: So because `a` is a formal A, the first look is on the methods in A. Because the method m1 in B has a different argument type than the one in A (although the argument type in B is actually a better fit), the method in A is chosen. For m4(), the method of B is chosen, because it overrides the method in A and `a` is a B under the hood. Is that right?